# Clicking on cancel button not returning to my ios app

Tags: ios, oauth, gmail, contacts

Can anyone please help me out ,iam fetching contacts from gmail using Oauthx to my ios           app.
After entering the credentials to gmail iam getting all the contacts till here its fine , but for the next time if i try again to fetch the contacts it wont direct to login page,

it opens safari and alert the user with an Alert showing "Do you want to open this link in your app".
   if i click open it calls my Callback URL and takes back to my app,
and if i click on cancel it wont redirect to my app.
How can i go back to app even if i click on cancel.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set urltypes in your info.plist

Comment: Hi @Divz ,i already used one urltype(i.e callbackURL for open click on alert) to return to my app,is it possible to give another callback url for the Cancel click on the alert ,so it should come back to app after clicking cancel.Can you just guide me,i already added another urltype for cancel,but not getting how to pass with appid.

Comment: you can use multiple url types such as for facebook google accounts and twitter accounts and you can not manage to create a alert box on cancel and then comes back into the application. This is automatically manages by using url trype and openUrl methods which Api's you are using please let me know and then i can solve your problm

Comment: Hi @Divz you dint get my point,iam not trying to create a alertbox,se for the 1st time after login to gmail to fecth contacts,iam geting back to app using Oauthx callbackURL,if i close the app and run it again and if you go again for fetching contacts it wont give you login page,the gmail credentials are getting saved,so it returns you to safari,takes the previous credentials without showing login page, and it returns an alert showing(would you like to open this link in your app)with two buttons OPEN and Cancel,there if i click open it returns to my app,but if i click cancel not returning.

Comment: iam using OAuthX classes for authorization to Gmail,its not an API.